# Logstash Multiline filter for websphere/java logs

Tags: regex, logging, logstash, multiline

Hello i have problem with my logstash multiline configuration. I'm parsing websphere/java logs and multiline don't work on some cases of logs.

My multiline configuration looks like this. I tried several types of regex but no one worked.

```
 codec => multiline {
     pattern => "^\A%{SYSLOG5424SD}"
     negate => true
     what => previous
 }
```

This is example of log that is not parsed in right way:

```
[1.6.2015 15:02:46:635 CEST] 00000109 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method     "processCommand" on bean     "BeanId(Issz_Produkcia_2.1.63#Ssz_Server_EJB.jar#CommandDispatcherImpl, null)".   Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.java:62)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:85)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.completeTxTimeout(TransactionControlImpl.java:1347)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:273)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:579)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4874)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.entitymanagers.EJSLocal0SLDokumentManagerImpl_18dd4eb4.findAllDokumentPripadByCriteriaMap(EJSLocal0SLDokumentManagerImpl_18dd4eb4.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.DataAccessServiceImpl.executeDokumentCmd(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:621)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.DataAccessServiceImpl.executeCmd(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:220)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.EJSLocal0SLDataAccessServiceImpl_6e5b0656.executeCmd(EJSLocal0SLDataAccessServiceImpl_6e5b0656.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.CommandDispatcherImpl.processSoloCommand(CommandDispatcherImpl.java:222)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.CommandDispatcherImpl._processCommand(CommandDispatcherImpl.java:151)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.CommandDispatcherImpl.processCommand(CommandDispatcherImpl.java:100)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.EJSLocal0SLCommandDispatcherImpl_b974dd5c.processCommand(EJSLocal0SLCommandDispatcherImpl_b974dd5c.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.SszServiceImpl.process(SszServiceImpl.java:146)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c.process(EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb._EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie.process(_EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb._EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie.java)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:678)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:525)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:576)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1578)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3076)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2946)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
 Caused by: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.java:62)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:85)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.completeTxTimeout(TransactionControlImpl.java:1347)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:273)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:579)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4874)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.entitymanagers.EJSLocal0SLDokumentManagerImpl_18dd4eb4.findAllDokumentPripadByCriteriaMap(EJSLocal0SLDokumentManagerImpl_18dd4eb4.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.DataAccessServiceImpl.executeDokumentCmd(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:621)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.DataAccessServiceImpl.executeCmd(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:220)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.EJSLocal0SLDataAccessServiceImpl_6e5b0656.executeCmd(EJSLocal0SLDataAccessServiceImpl_6e5b0656.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.CommandDispatcherImpl.processSoloCommand(CommandDispatcherImpl.java:222)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.CommandDispatcherImpl._processCommand(CommandDispatcherImpl.java:151)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.CommandDispatcherImpl.processCommand(CommandDispatcherImpl.java:100)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.EJSLocal0SLCommandDispatcherImpl_b974dd5c.processCommand(EJSLocal0SLCommandDispatcherImpl_b974dd5c.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.SszServiceImpl.process(SszServiceImpl.java:146)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb.EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c.process(EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb._EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie.process(_EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie.java)
at sk.sits.upsvar.server.ejb._EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemote0SLSszService_8e2ee81c_Tie.java)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:678)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:525)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:576)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1578)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3076)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2946)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
```

It's parsed by lines and i need it parsed together. I don't know if there is some character which is dividing them.

I tried these patterns:

```
pattern => "%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}]"
pattern => "^\["
pattern => "\A"
```

And a lot more i don't remember them all. Can someone who faced this problem help me.

Thanks you a lot.

Here is my full configuration.

```
input {
    file {  
        path => "D:\Log\Logstash\testlog.log"
        type => "LOG"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => plain {
            charset => "ISO-8859-1"
        }
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\A%{SYSLOG5424SD}"
            negate => true
             what => previous
        }
    } 
}
filter {
    grok{
        match => [ "message",".*exception.*"]
        add_tag => "exception"
    }
    mutate{
        remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
    }
    grok    {
        match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:}] %{WORD:} %{WORD:}\s* W"]
        add_tag => "Warning"
        remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
    }
    grok    {
        match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:}] %{WORD:} %{WORD:}\s* F"]
        add_tag => "Fatal"
        remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
    }
    grok    {
        match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:}] %{WORD:} %{WORD:}\s* O"]
        add_tag => "Message"
        remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
    }
    grok    {
        match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:}] %{WORD:} %{WORD:}\s* C"]
        add_tag => "Config"
        remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
    }
    #if ("Warning" not in [tags]) {
        grok    {
            match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:}] %{WORD:} %{WORD:}\s* E"]
            add_tag => "Error"
            remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
        }
    #}else {
        grok    {
            match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:}] %{WORD:} %{WORD:   }\s* I"]
            add_tag => "Info"
        }
    #}
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* . (.*\s){0,}%{GREEDYDATA:OBSAH}" ]
    remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
    }
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* . (.*\s){0,}%{WORD:WAS_CODE}:%{GREEDYDATA:OBSAH}" ]
                                            #"message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* W \s*\[SID:%{WORD:ISSZSID}]%{GREEDYDATA:OBSAH}"]
        remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
        add_tag => "was_error"
    }
    if ("was_error" not in [tags]) { 
        grok {
            match => [ "message","%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:zone}] %{WORD:ID} %{WORD:CLASS}\s* . \s*\[SID:%{WORD:ISSZSID}]%{GREEDYDATA:OBSAH}" ]
            remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
        }
        if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
            if [ISSZSID] != "null" {
                mutate{ 
                    add_tag => "ISSZwithID"
                    remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
                }
            } else {
                mutate{
                    add_tag => "ISSZnull"
                    remove_tag => "_grokparsefailure"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

output {
    if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
            #protocol => "http"
        }
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Comment: `codec => multiline {` looks very wrong ... `multiline`is a filter, can you share your full configuration?

Comment: I edited question and added full configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as assumed using `multiline` as a codec along with another codec is rather not what it was intended for. I'd rather use it as single codec or as filter.

Transform your configuration into this and you will get the results you look for:

```
input {
  file {    
    path => "D:\Log\Logstash\testlog.log"
    type => "LOG"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain { charset => "ISO-8859-1" }
  } 
}
filter {
    multiline {
        pattern => "^\A%{SYSLOG5424SD}"
        negate => true
        what => previous
    }
    # ... all other filters 
}
output {
 # your output definitions
}
```

A famous multiline parsing example is the one from Jordan Sissle on MySQL Log parsing: https://gist.github.com/jordansissel/3753353

Cheers

Comment: Now i have problem with workers. I can have only one at time because of multiline in filter ont in input. Is there any solution for this? And i dont know why with 1 worker is not parsing my file. When i change it back to my configuration and more workers its working again.

Comment: Right - multiline has some significant drawbacks.  Dropping the other codec could be an option but might result in broken characters.